# Custom Menu Styling With CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I am currently frustrated. I want to style this custom menu in the following way:
I want to center it while maintaining it's custom underline. The underline should be the same length all throughout while the words are centered and about 4px above the underline so that the letters do not directly touch the underline. 
The background image should (if possible) not be blocked by the white background color of the menu. 
I have tried using

```
display: inline-block; margin: 0 auto;
```

whilst zeroing out the other menu ***ul*** and ***li*** elements as suggesting in most solutions to somewhat similar problems but none has worked so far. 
Also something like

```
margin: 0 20%;
float: left; /*or right, re displays the underline but messes up the text in the below section. It all just goes to the left or right just like display: inline-block */
```

does not work across screens. 
It is also important to note that I did not put anything about sticky menus but the menu is sticky which is annoying.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to support really old browsers, use flexbox!

```
.menu-navmenu_tr-container {
    display: flex;
}
```

and on this style:

```
.elementor-widget-wp-widget-nav_menu ul {
    background-color: transparent;
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 1em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1080px;
    width: 80%;
    float: left;
}
```

remove the width and float.

For your fixed issue, this is the style doing it - it is located in custom.css:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 60em)
.anchor-menu-fixed.elementor-widget-wp-widget-nav_menu, .site-header-hidden.elementor-widget-wp-widget-nav_menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 7;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply @mikeg452. It is now acceptably in the middle, but still the underline won't show up. Also there is no such code in my custom.css.
https://jsfiddle.net/gordondavito/joc6d2my/ 
you can check out the all updated cutom.css code from the link above. 
Actuallyam still looking for the style: 
.elementor-widget-wp-widget-nav_menu ul
It must be generated by the plugin automatically.  I made up for it by hardcoding it in the custom.css file but so far just the positioning was changed. the other problems persist.

Comment: Indeed, it was some other plugin that created this second custom.css, I located it and as you said it was the one causing the fixedness. now thats one problem taken care of. :)

Comment: The custom underline appears to be showing up on your site when I view it. You also have a text-decoration: underline being applied which makes it looks a lot worse.

.navmenu li:hover>a, .navmenu a:focus, .navmenu a:hover {
change the text-decoration to none and     background-position-y to 4px and it looks a lot better.

Comment: Yes, part of the plugin css was in the way blocking the underline as well. By the way, the text decoration over there is already set to none. But the underline is still showing. I guess again some other part is still interfering but I can not find it. By the way how can I fix the length of all the other tabs to look like just like the one of referenslar. And Also to maintain that padding from the word to the underline? Except all words will be centered around it. Especially the shorter ones?

Comment: You may need to set a width value for the li's as the underline is currently being added as a 100% width background image. Setting them all to 180px wide and text-align: center will make the underlines consistent, but will make responsive behaviour more difficult to set up.

I've confirmed that .navmenu li { width: 180px;
    text-align: center; } does fix your problem at desktop size.

Comment: OMG, it worked, you really are a guru. How do I go about making it responsive, though? do I have to write the menu rules for each screen size? Ah, this refera... word. It is the only one that's not centered on its underline now. I wonder why, I checked even the characters and they are all the same. Thanks by the way :)

Comment: The main break points are 1170 (which you can solve by dropping the width from 180 to 165 and lowering the font size by 1-2 points and 980, where it goes to a mobile style menu. Do you want all the items to stay visible vertically, or add a button that slides them down?

Comment: adding a button would be ok.  how about the referans word underline. Isn't its behavior odd?

Comment: I'm not seeing any weird behavior with the underline.

For the mobile menu you could always use something like: https://wordpress.org/plugins/responsive-menu/

Comment: no no, I mean. all other words are perfectly centered but the "referanslar" word is off. Its not as well centered as the others